# Blazor - Padding/Margin Issues with Dynamically created <li>

Tags: html, css, blazor

Framework: .Net6.0

C#: 10.0

I'm using the following code, which partly comes comes from: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_calendar.asp

```
<div>
    <div class="month">      
        <ul>
            <li>
                @DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM")<br>
                <span style="font-size:18px">@DateTime.Today.Year</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <ul class="weekdays">
        <li class="border border-secondary">Mo</li>
        <li class="border border-secondary">Tu</li>
        <li class="border border-secondary">We</li>
        <li class="border border-secondary">Th</li>
        <li class="border border-secondary">Fr</li>
        <li class="border border-secondary">Sa</li>
        <li class="border border-secondary">Su</li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul class="days">
        <li class="border border-secondary">x</li>
        <li class="border border-secondary">x</li>
        <li class="border border-secondary">x</li>
        
        @for (int y = 0; y < (int)DateTime.Today.StartOfMonth().AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek; y++) {
            <li class="border border-secondary"></li>
        }

        @for (int x = 1; x < DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month) + 1; x++) {
            if (x == DateTime.Today.Day) {
                <li class="border border-secondary"><span class="active">@x</span></li>
            } else {
                <li class="border border-secondary">@x</li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

The issue comes from the Dynamically created `<li>` tags.
The ones created manually have a padding which is needed, however when the same `<li>` tag is created dynamically, there is no padding. Does anyone know why this happens?

[image]

***EDIT:***
`@preservewhitespace true` at the top of the razor file fixed this issue. Editor shows error, but still compiles and adds all the padding.

Comment: Might be related to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/blazor-components-trim-insignificant-whitespace. Check if adding `@preservewhitespace true` fixes the problem.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos I've updated my question to include my Framework. I don't think this is applicable to .net 6. The '@preservewhitespace true' is not availble

Comment: This was added in ASP.NET Core 5.0 though. Sometimes ide doesn't recognise it and shows red underline. Just give it a try if you want, won't take more than 10 seconds.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos I'm so sorry, you are right. The editor does say something is wrong, but it does run and adds the padding. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@preservewhitespace true` at the top of the razor file resolved this problem.